# How to return a value or conditionally raise an error in Ruby?

Tags: ruby

I am calling an API from a Rails model and I would like to raise an error if the API returns on non-200 code. Otherwise I want to cache/lazy-load the data. This is my method:

```
def data
    @data ||= SNL.get_list(name)
    raise StandardError, @data.inspect unless @data.success?
    @data
end
```

This works but I was wondering if I can accomplish this in one line. I tried using the `and` operator combined with an `unless` but couldn't get it to work.

Update: I have accepted tokland's answer because I asked for one line and he/she provided two very good solutions. In the end I am actually going to use

```
def data
  @data ||= SNL.get_list(name)
  @data.success? ? @data : (raise StandardError, @data.inspect)
end
```

for readability. I just hated having a third line just to return `@data`, since an exception will rarely be raised. I feel odiszapc's answer is a the best compromise of brevity and readability. Thanks everyone.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I wouldn't strain to write a one-liner, but you can use `tap` if you absolutely must:

```
def data
  (@data ||= SNL.get_list(name)).tap { |d| d.success? or raise StandardError.new(d.inspect) }
end
```

Also with short-circuited logic:

```
def data
  (@data ||= SNL.get_list(name)).success? && @data or
    raise StandardError.new(@data.inspect) }
end
```

Answer (score 2):

You can just use a terneray operator. However, I think its really important to keep your code as readable as possible. And generally in my experience, code that spreads a bit too much horizontally is generally a bit tough to follow.

There is one thing you need to be sure of. If `SNL.get_list(name)` returns nil and you're trying to use the `and` operator along with it, it won't work.

This issue has happened with me numerous times. A sample example:

```
nil and puts 'hello'
```

try this in your irb. It won't work. This issue has occurred with me numerous times.

Comment: ok,and will not allow 'puts' to be called due to its "short-circuitin" behavior, false and (what ever is it would be ignored!!). NO ISSUE!, try puts "Sab" and nil    :D

Comment: I'm afraid I can't understand what you're trying to say

Comment: ah sorry for formatting comments did not allows me to separate code from normal text, what output you are excepting from "nil and puts 'hello'" ?

Comment: nil
The point i'm trying to raise as a general FYI is that if anyone tries to do something like for example(just an example)
(@data ||= SNL.get_list(name)) and raise StandardError, @data.inspect unless @data.success?
if the get_list returns nil, second piece of code will never run

Comment: Yeah Agreed valid point!!, but it seems data can never be nil as "@data.success?" would have to break

Comment: True. I was talking in general :) i.e. its a mistake I generally make and debugging it is really cumbersome

Comment: `@data` is always a Response object. It is never nil. It's no so much that I want it all on one line, its more that it seems a shame to have to have a line just to return `@data` when 99% of the time there will be no exception.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe

```
def data
  @data ||= SNL.get_list(name)
  @data.success? ? @data : (raise StandardError, @data.inspect)
end
```

Or I'm not sure, something like:

```
def data
  (@data ||= SNL.get_list(name)).success? ? @data : (raise StandardError, @data.inspect)
end
```

Answer (score 1):

try

```
def data
    (@data ||= SNL.get_list(name)).success? ? @data :  raise(StandardError, @data.inspect)
end
```

Again @Sohaib's point is valid this is not quite readable! and not a rubbish's way, lot of parentheses